# Loading offline tiles as QgsRasterLayer in C++ or Python?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, tiles, c++

I have created tiles via Qtiles plugin in QGIS.

Here is the code snippet I have so far:

```
QString url = "file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/TiledMap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
QgsRasterLayer * lyr = new QgsRasterLayer ( url, "tiledLayer", "wms" );
QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(lyr , true);
```

The layer does not show up though. What am I missing? Is there something wrong with the URL?

I originally created the tiles via QTiles plugin using the following options:

Minimum zoom level: 5, Mazimum zoom level: 12

Comment: Which qgis version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.14

Comment: Upgrade to a recent version -- support for this was added in qgis 3.